# Converting text of textarea in a text file while uploading through php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, oracle

I am using a textarea for input of text in my application of PHP and using data type Varchacr2 in oracle 10g to store the text of this textarea -

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$note=$_REQUEST['note'];
$order = "INSERT INTO ec_note (nid, idno, note, flag, ec_date) VALUES (abc_seq.nextval,'$id', '$note',1,sysdate)";
if ($note)
{
$result = dbi_query($conn, $order); //order executes
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<textarea class="form-control rmcorner" name="note" rows="10"></textarea>
<button type="submit" name="notesubmit" onSubmit="window.location.reload()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add Note</button>
</form>
```

The amount of text in the textarea would be around 300 to 400 characters in most of the cases but it may exceed to around 20000 characters or more. The problem is oracle does not support text input for more than 4000 characters for varchar2 or any other datatype.

The only solution left is to save this in a file, but since in most of the cases the user has to put only 300-400 characters i don't want to use file upload.

So, I came up with an idea but not a solution. The idea is, let the user type the text in textarea upto their choice and lets put the text in the database if the text is upto 4000 characters as datatype varchar2 and if the text character exceeds 4000, the text of the textarea may be uploaded as a file in the server with a name.

I want to convert the text into a textfile and upload it as a file when the characters increase 4000, without prompting anything to the user.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Oracle is the top of the top database servers... just choose your datatype wisely

Comment: I want to convert the text into a textfile and upload it as a file when the characters increase 4000, without prompting anything to the user.